# Is there a way to change a UIBarButtonItem immediately in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I added a "favorite icon" (a heart) in the top Navigation Bar:

```
var faveMeItem = UIBarButtonItem (title: dua.isFavorite() ? "❤️" : "", style: .Plain, target: self, action: "toggleFav")
```

Is there a way to ensure it is changed (to a broken heart) as soon as it is tapped?

I have to go back to the tableView and come back to the detail, and then I see the updated icon.  Tapping on it does the logic, but the heart is not updated.   These are the functions in my Dua Class.

```
func removeFromFavorites() {
    //retrieve all favorites
    let favoriteDuaIds = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey(Dua.favoriteDuasKey) as! [Int]?
    if let favoriteDuaIds = favoriteDuaIds {
        //iterate through all Duas and comapre their IDs
        let newFavoriteDuaIds = favoriteDuaIds.filter { favoriteDuaId in
            return favoriteDuaId != duaId
        }
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(newFavoriteDuaIds, forKey: Dua.favoriteDuasKey)
    }
}

func isFavorite() -> Bool {
    //retrieve all favorites
    let favoriteDuaIds = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey(Dua.favoriteDuasKey) as! [Int]?
    if let favoriteDuaIds = favoriteDuaIds {
        //iterate through all Duas and comapre their IDs
        for favoriteDuaId in favoriteDuaIds {
            print (favoriteDuaId)
            if favoriteDuaId == duaId {
                return true
            }
        }
    }
    return false
}

func toggleFavorite() {
    if isFavorite() {
        removeFromFavorites()
    } else {
        addToFavorites()
    }
}

class func favorites() -> [Dua] {
    let favoriteDuaIds = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey(favoriteDuasKey) as! [Int]?
    if let favoriteDuaIds = favoriteDuaIds {
        return DuasDataSource.duas.filter { dua in
            return favoriteDuaIds.contains(dua.duaId)
        }
    } else {
        return []
    }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
func toggleFavorite() {
    if isFavorite() {
        removeFromFavorites()
    } else {
        addToFavorites()
    }
faveMeItem.title = dua.isFavorite() ? "❤️" : "" //Add this
}
```

Comment: You get that error because faveMeItem is out of scope of that function. Where do you initialize faveMeItem? I assumed its under your class declaration as a var.

Comment: If it is a var of a subclassed navigationController you would want to call `navigationController.faveMeItem.reloadView()`

Comment: I get this message now: Value of type 'UIBarButtonItem' has no member 'reloadView'  --- I have it declared under :  override func viewDidLoad() {

Comment: Right its a UIBarItem not a UIView. I think what is happening is it only switches to what its supposed to be when the viewcontroller is loaded. You don't update the title, just the bool. I updated the answer and I hope it works this time.